# Retrieve number from string, If count of digits of that number is greater than or equal to 4

Tags: python, string, python-re

```
Str1 = TC_11601662 - Group 0: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation
Str2 = TC_100 - Group 1: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation
Str3 = TC_1001 - Group 2: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation
```

trying to retrieve number from string If count of digits of that number is greater than or equal to 4, in this case skip `Str2`. Any help should be helpful.

```
out: 11601662 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions (RegEx) for this.

```
import re

strings = [
    'Str1 = TC_11601662 - Group 0: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation',
    'Str2 = TC_100 - Group 1: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation',
    'Str3 = TC_1001 - Group 2: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation'
]

numbers = [number for string in strings for number in re.findall('(\d{4,})', string)]
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['11601662', '1001']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) to parse your lines.

You should be careful not to just compare any 4 digit values, as your Groups may well exceed 999, and you'd get a lot of false positives.

```
import re

str1 = (
    "TC_11601662 - Group 0: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation"
)
str2 = "TC_100 - Group 1: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation"
str3 = "TC_1001 - Group 2: CPU Lockstep alarms to reaction reset and FSP0 activation"
strs = [str1, str2, str3]

pattern = r"TC_(\d{4,}) - Group \d+: .+"

test_case_numbers = []
for string in strs:
    match = re.match(pattern, string)
    if match:
        test_case_number = match.group(1)
        test_case_numbers.append(test_case_number)


for number in test_case_numbers:
    print(number, end=' ')
```

```
11601662 1001
```

For the regular expression:

- `(\d{4,})`: a [capturing group](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) that looks for a sequence of digits
  with at least 4 or more digits.
- `.+` matches the description